# Ssl авторизация

Tags: ssl, php, авторизация

Подскажите. Есть сайт http://yandex.ru, т.е. используется без https. Необходимо пустить пользователя через шифрование: пользователь вводит логин, пароль, нажимает "авторизоваться", данные уходят на https://passport.yandex.ru/login, и он авторизуется на всех поддоменах, в том числе и на http. То есть получается, его авторизует с поддомена на ВСЕ поддомены и авторизует как на http, так и на https.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport, наверное, ставит cookie, доступную для всех поддоменов: `Domain=yandex.ru;` и для всех протоколов - без уточнения `HttpOnly` или `Secure`.